# Is there a reason not to use Func for one off functions?

Tags: c#

is there a reason I should do

```
public class Foo {
  int Bar() {
    return 1;
  }
  public void Baz() {
     int bar = Bar();
     // do other stuff
  }
}
```

vs

```
public class Foo {
  public void Baz() {
    Func<int> Bar = ()=> {
      return 1;
    };
    int bar = Bar();
    // do other stuff
  }
}
```

I would like to do the latter in order to show the intent that Bar exists solely for execution by Baz, but I don't want to do it if there are problems with it.

Comment: I think it might be slightly less efficient, since the function object is being allocated at runtime? It's also probably less familiar to most C# programmers. Personally I'd only use it if the function needs to capture local variables of Baz(), but I don't think there's anything too bad about it - it does show the intent as a helper function as you say.

Comment: C# design question-- Skeet(lang c#){return answer;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perfectly vaild, smart looking, I would never do it in code to be used by somone else. If you and whoever else will be looking at this code are used to this style I see no problems with it.

Pro:

- clearly shows scope
- very functional looking

Con:

- Function becomes much longer (especially if you don't use K&R curly braces style)
- Very non-traditional for C# code. Inline lambdas are used everywhere now, but explicit functions like this are not widely used.
- Could unintentionally capture state from outer function.
- Likley to get small performance hit and unlikley to be inlined by JIT.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this in most languages, but not C#.  The notation (specifying the `Func<>` type, making an empty parameter list sigil) is just too clunky-looking, and it's not idiomatic.  I would prefer having a private method even if that method doesn't make sense anywhere else.

Comment: hm, guess it's a matter of taste :-)

Comment: the empty parameter list and one line of code in the function was for the simplicity of an example.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't going to be any problems if you put equivalent code inside a lambda instead of a proper method. There might be a couple of things you need to watch out for (e.g. making sure you don't accidentally create a closure), but assuming the refactoring itself doesn't introduce a bug the code will run just as well.

However, IMHO the decision to use a proper method vs an inline lambda should not be based on the number of times the method is to be used. My personal rule is:

Use a lambda if the code is performing a function of narrow scope (e.g. a predicate that filters a collection) and is only meaningful in that scope -- in other words, if it "takes care of the really small print". If the code does something relevant to the high-level functionality of the class that contains it, put it in a proper method.

Comment: the closure issue is definitely something to worry about

Answer (score 0):

no there is no reason. it is perfectly legal to use `Func`s as inline functions like that

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking; wouldn't setting it to 'private' accomplish the same thing?  It would convey the idea that it isn't intended for external consumption?

I think your approach is 100% acceptable.  The biggest problem I'd see with it in a production/team setting is that people (who aren't familar with it) would say it is 'confusing'.

Comment: Private is close but the issue is that the OP's code is private to a particular method not the class.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I really did miss the point; but now it makes sense.  +1